# Why does optional-chaining multiple property accesses throw for an empty object, but not for null?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

in a node repl or browser console:

```
> ({})?.a
undefined
> (null)?.a
undefined
> (null)?.a.b
undefined
> ({})?.a.b
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b')
```

if `(anything)?.a` is `undefined` then why does the `undefined` that `(null)?.a` evaluates to *NOT* throw an error when I read its non-existent properties?

Comment: `({})` is not `undefined`, but there's no "a" property in that object so `({})?.a` is undefined, just like `({a: 1}).b` is `undefined`.

Comment: There is no `undefined` returned by `(null)?.a`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey OP might have used the wrong word. Yes, of course that statement doesn't "return" anything. But nonetheless, it "evaluates to" `undefined`

Comment: In different words, the optional chaining operator only short circuits chained operators when the object or function to be called supplied as the **left hand operand** of `.?` is `null` or `undefined`. Since `{}` is neither of those, evaluation continues without short circuiting and throws the error for the same reason `({}}.a.b` would throw attempting to look up the `b` property of `undefined`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61082928/5648954

Comment: @derpirscher I updated the question with "evaluates to", thank you!
@traktor that's exactly what I was looking for (add an answer?)! I wasn't thinking of `?.` as being capable of short-circuiting (My mental "javascript short circuit" model only included logical operators)

Comment: @derpirscher not sure why you deleted your answer?

Comment: @Bergi because I voted to close this question as duplicate. And it was already closed, not sure why it was reopened

Comment: @derpirscher I see. I kinda agree with traktor (the reopener) though, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139078/null-safe-property-access-and-conditional-assignment-in-es6-2015) doesn't answer the question at all, and doesn't explain the difference between  `(null)?.a.b` and `(null?.a).b`. The one NickParsons dug up is more suited as a duplicate, though all the info there is in the comments not the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does the `undefined` that `(null)?.a` evaluates to NOT throw an error when I read its non-existent properties?

It would:

```
> (null?.a).b
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b')
> const temp = null?.a;
> temp.b
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b')
```

The difference from that to `null?.a.b` is that the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) short-circuits the **entire** property access (and method call) **chain**, stopping evaluation and just returning `undefined`.

Comment: so... `null?.a` and `null?.a.b` both evaluate to `undefined` because `a` and `a.b` are irrelevant. Everything after the `?.` is ignored. Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 4):

It's working that way to allow you to check if an object exists, and then access multi-level properties if it does without needing a huge tree of checks against every level of the object. The case with (null)? is repeatable in two more ways that illustrate the principle:

```
(undefined)?.a.b.c.d 
({})?.a?.b.c.d
```

Both of those will also return undefined without throwing an error. As long as you've triggered a fail state with `?` already, it will let you reference subproperties safely to as many layers as you like

`({})?.a.b` throws an error because `{}` is defined and passes the check, but then you're not checking whether `a` is undefined before trying to access its properties